# If the delegate isn't set for a UITextField object, then who is carrying out those optional functions initially?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

I'm working through a tutorial where the focus is on teaching delegation and callbacks.  In the tutorial we're using a UITextField object and now we're expounding on this UITextField object by implementing the UITextFieldDelegate protocol.  We're using a custom viewController and setting this same viewController as the delegate.

The question I have is, who was the delegate before we decided to set the ViewController as the delegate?  Was the UITextField it's own delegate and carrying out these optional methods on its own?  And if so, by us implementing the UITextFieldDelegate, is the end goal to gain more customization or control of how the UITextField works?

Thank you in advance and apologies if I'm being too analytical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, the documentation for a delegate method will tell you what default to expect.  For example, `optional func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool` says, "If you do not implement this method, the text field **acts as if** this method had returned YES." (Emphasis mine.)

Also, you can inspect the delegate property before assigning a delegate and note that it is `nil`.

Putting these together, it seems that the text field uses an optional delegate to replace its own default, non-delegate behaviour.